# Unable to find a route in Laravel with Apache

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Every route I currently try in Laravel 4 is throwing a 404 error.

I only have two pages; the homepage, and a login page.

Now my issue is that I cant navigate to the `/login` route.

But when I change my login route to the default route which is `172.16.55.136/laravel/public/`, then it works.

So the login route is `172.16.55.136/laravel/public/login` which then gives me as 404.

This is the route file:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home' ,'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex'));

Route::get('/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'));
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'AuthController@postLogin'));
```

I also changed my apache2 config file to the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Is there something else that I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index directory should be the `public` folder in Laravel, as that is where the entrypoint exists (`public/index.php`)

Change your config to the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/laravel/public>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then just access your laravel app at `http(s)://hostname`

Comment: Thanks allot @Amelia for your help, my login window now appears to be in http://172.16.55.136/laravel/public/index.php/login